# Deferred Rendering not Displaying the GBuffer Textures

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, deferred-rendering

I'm trying to implement deferred rendering within an engine I'm developing as a personal learning, and I cannot get to understand what I'm doing wrong when it comes to render all the textures in the GBuffer to check if the implementation is okay.

The thing is that I currently have a framebuffer with 3 color attachments for the different textures of the GBuffer (color, normal and position), which I initialize as follows:

```
  glCreateFramebuffers(1, &id);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, id);

  std::vector<uint> textures;
  textures.resize(3);
  glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, textures.data());
  
  for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);

     if(i == 0)   // For Color Buffer
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
     else
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);

     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
     glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i], 0);
  }

  GLenum color_buffers[3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 };
  glDrawBuffers((GLsizei)textures.size(), color_buffers);

  uint depth_texture;
  glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &depth_texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_texture);
  glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth_texture, 0);

  bool fbo_status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE;
  ASSERT(fbo_status, "Framebuffer Incompleted!");
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

This is not reporting any errors and it seems to work since the framebuffer of the forward renderer renders properly. Then, when rendering, I run the next code after binding the framebuffer and clearing the color and depth buffers:

```
  camera_buffer->Bind();
  camera_buffer->SetData("ViewProjection", glm::value_ptr(viewproj_mat));
  camera_buffer->SetData("CamPosition", glm::value_ptr(glm::vec4(view_position, 0.0f)));
  camera_buffer->Unbind();

  for(Entity& entity : scene_entities)
  {
    shader->Bind();

    Texture* texture = entity.GetTexture();
    BindTexture(0, texture);

    shader->SetUniformMat4("u_Model", entity.transform);
    shader->SetUniformInt("u_Albedo", 0);
    shader->SetUniformVec4("u_Material.AlbedoColor", entity->AlbedoColor);
    shader->SetUniformFloat("u_Material.Smoothness", entity->Smoothness);

    glBindVertexArray(entity.VertexArray);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, entity.VertexArray.index_buffer.count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

    // Shader, VArray and Textures Unbindings
  }
```

So with this code I manage to render the 3 textures created by using the ImGui::Image function, by switching the texture index between 0, 1 or 2 as the next:

`ImGui::Image((ImTextureID)(fbo->textures[0]), viewport_size, ImVec2(0, 1), ImVec2(1, 0));`

Now, the color texture (at index 0) works perfectly, as the next image shows:
[image: color texture]

But when rendering the normals and position textures (indexes 2 and 3), I have no result:
[image: pos/norm texture]

Does anybody sees what I'm doing wrong? Because I've been hours and hours with this and I cannot see it. I ran this on RenderDoc and I couldn't see anything wrong, the textures displayed in RenderDoc are the same than in the engine.

The vertex shader I use when rendering the entities is the next:

```
  layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_Position;
  layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_TexCoord;
  layout(location = 2) in vec3 a_Normal;

  out IBlock
  {
    vec2 TexCoord;
    vec3 FragPos;
    vec3 Normal;
  } v_VertexData;

  layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform ub_CameraData
  {
    mat4 ViewProjection;
    vec3 CamPosition;
  };

  uniform mat4 u_ViewProjection = mat4(1.0);
  uniform mat4 u_Model = mat4(1.0);

  void main()
  {
    vec4 world_pos = u_Model * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
    
    v_VertexData.TexCoord = a_TexCoord;
    v_VertexData.FragPos = world_pos.xyz;
    v_VertexData.Normal = transpose(inverse(mat3(u_Model))) * a_Normal;
    
    gl_Position = ViewProjection * u_Model * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
  }
```

And the fragment one is the next, they are both pretty simple:

```
  layout(location = 0) out vec4 gBuff_Color;
  layout(location = 1) out vec3 gBuff_Normal;
  layout(location = 2) out vec3 gBuff_Position;

  in IBlock
  {
    vec2 TexCoord;
    vec3 FragPos;
    vec3 Normal;
  } v_VertexData;

  struct Material
  {
    float Smoothness;
    vec4 AlbedoColor;
  };

  uniform Material u_Material = Material(1.0, vec4(1.0));
  uniform sampler2D u_Albedo, u_Normal;

  void main()
  {
    gBuff_Color = texture(u_Albedo, v_VertexData.TexCoord) * u_Material.AlbedoColor;
    gBuff_Normal = normalize(v_VertexData.Normal);
    gBuff_Position = v_VertexData.FragPos;
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try running your application in RenderDoc, it may give you a clue as to what is going wrong

Comment: Yes, in the question I already say that I used RenderDoc to debug this and I can't find anything

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, _reproducible_ example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As the question is currently written, almost all of the GL state at draw time is unknown.

Comment: Also, if you already have used renderdoc, look at the actual texture contents. Rendering this with Imgui just adds even more unknowns. Btw., it might be as simple as your alpha channel ending up at 0.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I see, but changing all the values to GL_RGBA8 does not work, is there something else to do in this direction?

Comment: @derhass Well, the parts of the code that I don't specify (like the Uniforms set, for instance) it's because they already work properly in Forward Rendering, so they should not be failing

About RenderDoc, I'm not sure what texture contents I need to take a look at (I'm also a beginner in RenderDoc)

Comment: @derhass About the alpha thing, the Color texture is working and the others are vec3, I don't see how they can have the alpha at 0

Comment: "About the alpha thing, the Color texture is working and the others are vec3". Exactly _because_ of that I talk about the alpha value. YOur attachment is `GL_RGBA16F` (as it should be, since `GL_RGB16F` is not a required color-renderable format), so what do you think you alpha channel _will_ be here? Hint: a fragment shader color output is _always_ vec4 (the fixed-function fragment processing stages following after the fragment shader all work on RGBA values), if you don't write to all compenents, the value is just undefined.

Comment: Oh holy christ that was it, I don't know how I didn't see that before. The thing is that I was following the learnopengl.com tutorial and it uses vec3 for position and normals, so I guess I just wrote it like that and ignored it.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, @derhass, this was driving me crazy... If you want to formally answer the question I will be happy to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the question what exactly might be happening here, as lots of  GL states - both at the time the rendering to the gbuffer, and at that time the gbuffer texture is rendered for visualization - are just unknown. However, from the images given in the question, one can *not* conclude that the actual color output for attachments 1 and 2 is not working.

One issue which comes to mind is alpha blending. The color values processed by the per-fragment operations after the vertex shader are always working with RGBA values - although the *value* of the A channel only matters if you enabled blending and use a blend function which somehow depends on the source alpha.

If you declare a custom fragment shader output as `float`, `vec2`, `vec3`, the remaining components stay undefined (undefined value, not undefined behavior). This does not impose a problem unless some other operations you do depend on those values.

What we also have here is a `GL_RGBA16F` output format (which is the right choice, because none of the 3-component RGB formats are required as color-renderable by the spec).

What *might* happen here is either:

- Alpha blending is already turned on during rendering into the g-buffer. The fragment shader's alpha output happens to be zero, so that it appears as 100% transparent and the contents of the texture are not changed.
- Alpha blending is not used during rendering into the g-buffer, so the correct contents end up in the texture, the alpha channel just happens to end up with all zeros. Now the texture might be visualized with alpha blending enbaled, ending up in a 100% transparent view.

If it is the first option, turn off blending when rendering the into the g-buffer. It would not work with deferred shading anyway. You might still run into the second option then.

If this is the second  option, there is no issue at all - the lighting passes which follow will read the data they need (and ultimately, you will want to put useful information into the alpha channel to not waste it and be able to reduce the number of attachments). It is just your visualization (which I assume is for debug purposed only) is wrong. You can try to fix the visualization.

As a side note: Storing the world space position in the G-Buffer is a huge waste of bandwidth. All you need to be able to reconstruct the world space position is the depth value and the inverse of your view and projection matrices. Also storing world space position in `GL_RGB16F` will very easily run into precision issues if you move your camera away from world space origin.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know what other GLenum values are prefered to use with position or normals?

Comment: As I said: you don't store positions. For storing normals, there are several options, see [this paper](http://jcgt.org/published/0003/02/01/) for some options.